# Onclick function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which allows me to click on an item and change the value.  In order to optimise it for older browsers (IE8) i changed how the table is drawn from appending `<td>` elements each time, to concatenating a string and then appending the item all at once.  However in my new string append the attached function doesnt get called.

Here is the code snippet i had which worked:

```
             $('<td>', {
                 'text': value,
                 'class': 'editableCell',
                 'data-hd': currentCell.hd,
                 'data-cl': currentCell.cl,
                 'click': editFunction
            }).appendTo(tr_body);
```

I changed this to:

```
tableString += '<td class="selectable" data-hd="' + currentCell.hd+ '" data-cl="' + currentCell.cl+ '" onclick="editFunction()">' + value + '</td>';
```

And now when i click the element i get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: blurEdit is not defined`

Any ideas what the difference is between the first `click: editFunction` and the second `onclick='editFunction()'`?

The function is:

```
 var editFunction= function () {
     $(this).off();
     var value = $(this).text();
     var inp = $('<input>', {
         'type': 'text',
         'value': value,
         'class': 'form-control',
         'blur': blurEdit
     });
     $(this).html(inp);
     inp.focus();
 };
```

So it's getting this far and then failing with the blurEdit function which hasnt been changed.

Comment: If you are not calling the function from anywhere else, you can change the definition of it to `function editFunction() {`.

Comment: Yeah it gets called from a few places unfortunately.  It was the wrong function in the question though, not editFunction but blurEdit, another function being called from the editFunction, so i guess this works.

Comment: When the `click` event is triggered, the `editFunction` symbol has already been recycled in the second way of defining the `td`. Probably, the `editFunction` was local to the function where the `td` is generated. In the first way, the function reference itself will be preserved as click handler of the `td`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas what the difference is between the first click: editFunction and the second onclick='editFunction()'?

One assigns a reference to the function (from the current scope chain) to the event handler.

The other creates an new function that tries to access the aforementioned function it by name in a different scope chain (the intrinsic event handlers scope, which is something like "the onclick function itself, properties of the element object, window").

Go back to the first method. It is much cleaner and safer than trying to create HTML by smashing strings together.

Comment: I agree, unfortunately it was a requirement that i change it to the HTML version.  Thanks for the explanation